# Using urllib and BeautifulSoup to retrieve info from web with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I can get the html page using urllib, and use BeautifulSoup to parse the html page, and it looks like that I have to generate file to be read from BeautifulSoup.

```
import urllib                                       
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://SOMEWHERE") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
--> write to file
```

Is there a way to call BeautifulSoup without generating file from urllib?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
```

No file writing needed: Just pass in the HTML string. You can also pass the object returned from `urlopen` directly:

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://SOMEWHERE") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
```

Comment: For more recent versions `f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://SOMEWHERE")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the url, download the html, and make it parse-able in one shot with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup
soup = Soup.get("https://www.example.com/")
```